# Blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight... does not have HTTP ok status. Headers didn't solve the problem

Tags: node.js, angular, api, express, cors

guys! I am practicing MEAN stack development by building a task manager app, and currently running into CORS problem. I seem to have dug through whole internet trying different solutions, and went from one problem to another. Currently stuck on this one:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000//lists/602676b56197c004f12bbeaf/tasks/602676be6197c004f12bbeb0' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

I have stated this in my code(however it didn't solve the problem:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

I've also tried using browser extensions, disabling web security through terminal, didn't solve the problem, and as I remember, doing it with proxy didn't help in my previous project...

Just in case - this is how one of my requests looks like:

```
app.patch('/lists/:listId/tasks/:taskId', (req, res) => {
    Task.findOneAndUpdate({
            _id: req.params.taskId,
            _listId: req.params.listId
        }, {
            $set: req.body
        }
    ).then(() => {
        res.sendStatus(200);
    })
});
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong? What else I should pay attention to and try?
It is hard for me dealing with backend, since it is one of my very first times doing it...

Anyways, I hope someone can enlighten me on this issue, I would really appreciate it!

Cheers!

Comment: I can't help you, but from my experience i have had no success disabling CORS on patch requests. Just change them to POST's and continue on.

Comment: @ChrisR Check out the answers given, it worked for me, hope it's going to be helpful for you too

Answer (score 0):

don't implement cors functionality yourself. use the lib

```
npm install --save cors
....
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try cors package

install npm

```
npm i cors --save
```

then

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
....
```

this will allow cors everywhere hope it helps and make sure that app.use(cors()) is above all.